# Homomorphism and isomorphism from vector space $V$ to $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Can I show $\mathbb R^4$ is isomorphic to any general vector space without satisfying all axioms of the general $V$ mathematically?

Comment: So far all four posts of you have been problem-statement questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Thanks for link, shall improve question writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show that a general real vectorial space $V$ of dimension $n$ is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ once you fixed a basis $\mathcal{B} = \left\lbrace v_{1},\cdots v_{n} \right\rbrace$ of $V$ in the following way : define the coordinates map : $[]_{\mathcal{B}} : V \longmapsto \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $[v]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{pmatrix}a_{1} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n}\end{pmatrix}$ where $a_{i}$ is the $i$-th coefficient of $v$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}$, meaning $v = a_{1}v_{1}+\cdots a_{n}v_{n}$.

Show that this defines an isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Very beautiful answer, cleared my several doubts within a little span of time in Euclidean space.